# Sketch the curve described by $(x,y) = (3\cos t+2, 3\sin t -3)$

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, curves, parametric

> Sketch the curve described by these parametric equations.
>   $$\begin{align}
> x &=3\cos t+2 \\
> y &=3\sin t -3
> \end{align}$$ 
>   for $0 \leq t < 2\pi$.

I found the equation to be $$\left(\frac{y+3}{3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x-2}{3}\right)^2 = 1$$ 
hence centre to be $(2,-3)$ and can sketch the graph on the cartesian plane but I don't know how to sketch it with this: $0 \leq t < 2\pi$.

Can someone explain and send an image of what it would look like? Thanks!

Comment: Do you the cartesian equation of a circle?

Comment: What? @hamam_Abdallah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very straightforward, plug in values of $t$:  just notice the offset:

[image]

Here are some points and the $t$ values that led to them:

[image]

Clear now??

Comment: But what do I do for the  0 ≤ t < 2π I don't quite get how that will affect the graph and what changes I make.

Comment: I have gotten that graph; that's easy but I don't get how to use the 0 ≤ t < 2π and how it's going to affect which parts of the graph are accepted and which aren't

Comment: You *USE* $0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$ to *get* the circle.  Plug in $t=0$ to find one point on the plane; then plug in $t = 0.1$, then plug in $t=.2$... well, you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation can be written as

$$(x-2)^2+(y+3)^2=9=3^2$$

your curve is then a circle with the point $C(2,-3) $ as center and Radius $ R=3$.